# becomeFirstResponder is not showing keyboard until touch of any UITextField at least once

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, ios13, foundation

**Possible solution at the end.**

I am developing a `UIViewController` with three `UITextField`. The function to open the keyboard when the screen is presented was working for 3 years non-stop, then after the iOS 13 it stopped working. The same script is still working normally on iOS 11 and 12.

To make it work again I need to click to any `UITextField` (it doesn't need to be on the same screen) in the app. After that, all the `UITextField` in my app are triggering the keyboard.

No, I am not using the hardware keyboard and the problem also happens on a real iPhone X.

To open the keyboard I am doing this:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.textField.perform(
            #selector(self?.becomeFirstResponder),
            with: nil,
            afterDelay: 0.1)
    }
}
```

I tested it very well in multiple devices, also recorded a video showing a iOS 12 and iOS 13 running the same binary side by side and the function not working on the iOS 13.

Again, it only don't open the keyboard if the user **NEVER** click in **ANY** `UITextField` (or anything that opens the keyboard). Once you clicked in this type of component, the keyboard start opening again.

The app uses `UIScene` on iOS 13. Could this be the problem?

Is this a known bug on iOS 13? I am not sure how to solve this.

My setup:

- macOS 10.15.2
- Xcode 11.3
- Swift 5

Screenshot of the problem, same binary, same actions to go to this screen, different behaviour (the info from the `UIViewController` at the back was hidden manually):

[image]

Possible solution:

If you are using `Intercom` in your project. Simply add `Intercom.logout()` when your ViewController starts. After that, the problem is gone.

Comment: Same issue any one please answer

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed Are you using the Intercom library? By calling `Intercom.logout()` solves my problem.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm also experiencing this issue

Comment: @JulienS. Are you using Intercom?

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim I am not, just a regular uitextfield